# Any way to add Description field as reference to uploadfile which is save in ContentDocument in lightning

Tags: lightning

I have created a upload file component and trying to add description field for the file. and the File is save in contentdocument.

Comment: Hi @DurgaPrasad, it is not clear what you are asking here. Could you please provide some screenshots or code snippets of what you are trying to achieve? Which obstacles are you trying to cope?

Comment: Please share your code so we can help you better. Also - there is no option to add fields data to the `lightning:fileUpload` component. what you can do is handle the `onuploadfinished` that fires after the file was uploaded and then call the server a second time to update a specific field

Comment: Thanks Itai Shmida,  I have added the Description by Apex.